# MobileFirst 6.3 native API project empty /include folder on MacOS

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

Platform: MobileFirst Platform 6.3
OS: Mac OS

This only happens to my MacOS Eclipse, but OK on my Windows Eclipse

How to reproduce?
1) Create a MobileFrist Project
2) Select Native API
3) Select iOS
4) After the project is created, there should be a lot of *.h files in the /include folder.  But on the MacOS version, the /include folder has nothing.  However, this doesn't happen on my Windows version.

Please help.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading my MobileFirst Platform Studio to 6.3.0.00-201501060-1717, the problem on MacOS MFP Studio is resolved.  I can see all the *.h files from the /include folder.